# Use ASCII code to insert a line break in a Tooltip

Tags: visualforce, html, browser, character-encoding

I need to add a line break in a tooltip.  I tried using ASCII character `"&#13;"` to insert a new line feed.
This works like a charm in normal HTML page. It even works just fine when you add it through the Browser console. However, it is not rendered as a linefeed in case of a VF Page, all I see is `"Line 1 &#13; Line 2"` in the tooltip. So, I've the following questions.

1. How is the ASCII converted to special characters in a HTML page and where is it getting converted? Is the browser responsible?
2. How do I get it working in Salesforce VF Page?

Here is the sample I've tried. Thanks in advance!

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStyleSheets="false">
    <apex:outputText title="Line 1 &#13; Line 2" value="Hi" ></apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

[apex:outputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm) by default will escape all text entered in it. You will need to use  `escape="false"` to get the line break to appear.

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" title="Line 1 &#13; Line 2" value="Hi" ></apex:outputText>
```

> Be aware that setting this value to "false" may be a security risk
>   because it allows arbitrary content, including JavaScript, that could
>   be used in a malicious manner.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: You could try using the HTML `<br/>` tag instead of `&#13;`

Comment: Doesn't work either! Also, I cannot use escape="false"since I'm working with a managed package and will not clear security check from salesforce if I use it.